# Looping an array with async module

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

I have to do a query to the DB and then for each element in the result array I have to do another query, and then complete the code. I'm using async.waterfall to do the tasks and inside one function I use async.forEachSeries to do the looping.

```
async.waterfall([
    function(callback){
        connection.query(sql, params, function(err, rows, fields){
            if(err) throw err;
            callback(null, rows);
        })
    },
    function(rows, callback){
        var result = [];
        var aux = {};
        for(var i in rows){
            if(typeof aux[rows[i].id] == 'undefined'){
                var obj = {
                    'id': rows[i].id,
                    'title': rows[i].title,
                    'type': rows[i].type,
                    'url': rows[i].url,
                    'last_update': rows[i].last_update,
                    'unixend': rows[i].unixend,
                    'client_id': rows[i].id_client,
                    'client_name': rows[i].client_name,
                    'background_timeline': rows[i].background_timeline,

                    'description': rows[i].description,

                    'init': rows[i].init,
                    'end': rows[i].end,

                    'days': rows[i].days,
                    'timeinit': rows[i].timeinit,
                    'timeend': rows[i].timeend,
                    'lat': rows[i].lat,
                    'lon': rows[i].lon,
                    'url2': rows[i].url2,
                    //'locations': [ ],
                };
                aux[rows[i].id] = obj;
            }


        }
        callback(null, aux, result)
    },
    function(aux, result, callback){
        async.eachSeries(aux,
            function(obj, callback){
                connection.query(sql2, [obj['id'], obj['id'], obj['id']], function(err, data){
                    obj['locations'] = data;
                    callback();
                })
            },
            function(err){  
                if(err) throw err;
                else callback(null, aux, result)
            });
    },
    function(aux, result, callback){
        for(var i in aux){
            result.push(aux[i]);
        }
        callback(null, result);
    }
],
    function(err, result){
        if(err) callback1(err, []);
        else callback1(false, result);
    }
);
```

Here, callback1 is the callback passed as an argument to the global function when it's called. Also, sql and sql2 are the queries stored in variables.

The problem is that it never enters at the eachSeries method. Why is that?

Comment: You have a syntax error in this code, closing brace before callback(null, aux, result) is incorrect, it closes the function

Comment: It's a paste error, thanks, but that's not the problem

Comment: Are you sure, that you are getting into the second waterfall function?

Comment: Yes, I put a console.log in every function

Comment: The problem was that aux is an object, not an array